# When copy constructor or assignment constructor is called?

Tags: c++

Triny the quiz from web and see this code. The result prints is 02

Which means default copy constructor is used for list initialization while assignment constructor is used for vector. Why?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Int
{
public:
    Int(int i = 0) : m_i(i) { }

public:
    bool operator<(const Int& a) const { return this->m_i < a.m_i; }

    Int& operator=(const Int &a)
    {
        this->m_i = a.m_i;
        ++m_assignments;
        return *this;
    }

    static int get_assignments() { return m_assignments; }

private:
    int m_i;
    static int m_assignments;
};

int Int::m_assignments = 0;

int main()
{
    std::list<Int> l({ Int(3), Int(1) });
    l.sort();
    std::cout << (Int::get_assignments() > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    std::vector<Int> v({ Int(2), Int() });
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << (Int::get_assignments() > 0 ? 2 : 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which means default copy constructor is used for list initialization while assignment constructor is used for vector

If you remove the `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());` instruction the program prints `00`. The assignment operator is used just for sorting.

**NOTE**: the list can be sorted simply by modifying pointers (so `l.sort()` doesn't require `operator=`).